# How to set up pay pal express checkout without customer login in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, paypal-express

if it possible to Paypal express checkout work without a customer login.
Now it is redirected to the login page but I have no requirement to the customer login so how can I have done it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you Enable PayPal Guest Checkout https://drops.meetanshi.com/CpEq1P

so login not require guest user also can place order using paypal